# High autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit - why?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

**Update 2022-11-10: I have opened a case with AWS for this one and will let you know here once they have responded.**

Postgres 12.9 AWS Managed on db.r5.4xlarge which has 64GB RAM.

`autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` is at 1800:

`select setting from pg_settings where name = 'autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit'; -- 1800`

Parameter group in AWS Console:

`autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit: GREATEST({log(DBInstanceClassMemory/21474836480)*600},200)`

`rds.adaptive_autovacuum: 1`

Calculation for autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit IMHO:

`64 Gigabytes = 68,719,476,736 Bytes`

`GREATEST({log(68719476736/21474836480)*600},200)`

`GREATEST({log(3.2)*600},200)`

`GREATEST({0.50514997832*600},200)`

`GREATEST(303.089986992,200)`

CloudWatch Metric `MaximumUsedTransactionIDs` hovers around 200mio. Many tables are close to 200mio.

**So `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` should be 303 IMHO? Why is `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` at 1800? I would expect 303. I think I can rule out manual intervention. Thank you.**

Comment: Ask Amazon. Who else should know?

Comment: `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 1800` doesn't seem unreasonable for a busy system with a good I/O system. 303 is not that much more compared to the default of 200

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name TY. As per my research I get I/O of 160 MB/s for the EBS (3.3TB gp2 SSD). And as per my calculations an autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit of 1800 together with the other settings such as EBS latency < 10ms, autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 2ms, vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20, vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1, vacuum_cost_page_miss = 5, to me it seems that autovacuum is allowed to cause 100% I/O as with these settings it should get much more than 160MB/s. Am I wrong?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am still curious where the 1800 comes from, but trying on my laptop with SSD, the settings seem to be reasonable, as you say, wherever it might come from. With 3 parallel updates I get a write speed of 120mb/s. And with 3 parallel autovacuum I get 25mb/s read speed and 25mb/s write speed, so a reasonable load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from aws. In short, the explanation is twofold:

1. by "log" they mean "log base 2" and not "log base 10"
2. they are rounding at one point

```
The autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit formula is GREATEST({log(DBInstanceClassMemory/21474836480)*600},200).

Log in above formula is log of base 2 and the log value is rounded off before it is multiplied by 600.

As your instance's instance type is r5.2xlarge, the instance class memory is 64 gb.

DBInstanceClassMemory= 64 GiB =68719476736 bytes

Therefore, the following calculation is used to calculate the autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit value:

GREATEST({log(68719476736/21474836480)600},200)
= GREATEST({log(3.2)600},200) --> log base 2 of (3.2) is 1.678 which is rounded off to 2
= GREATEST({2*600},200)
= GREATEST({1200},200)
= 1200
```